# AIX 7.1 Python3 Installation: Symbol Resolution Issue

Tags: yum, aix, python3, dnf

I'm trying to install and run Python 3.9 on one of our AIX Operating Systems.

I used yum to install Python 3.9.

```
Current OS Level:
root@our_AIX_host:/opt/freeware/libexec > oslevel -s
7100-05-11-2246
```

Initially, there were some unresolved pathing issues that I had to rectify by adding to PATH and LIBPATH.

```
root@our_AIX_host:/opt/freeware/libexec > echo $LIBPATH
/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64
root@our_AIX_host:/opt/freeware/libexec > echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java8_64/jre/bin:/usr/java8_64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/erac/sysadmin/roster/bin:/usr/local/bin:/etc/emc/bin:/opt/LicenseUseManagement/bin:/opt/freeware/bin
```

When I try to run python3:

```
root@our_AIX_host:/opt/freeware/libexec > python3
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program python3 because of the following errors:
        0509-130 Symbol resolution failed for /usr/lib/libpython3.9.a[libpython3.9.so] because:
        0509-136   Symbol _GLOBAL__AIXI_libintl_so (number 284) is not exported from
                   dependent module /usr/lib/libintl.a[libintl.so.8].
        0509-136   Symbol _GLOBAL__AIXD_libintl_so (number 285) is not exported from
                   dependent module /usr/lib/libintl.a[libintl.so.8].
        0509-026 System error: Error 0
        0509-192 Examine .loader section symbols with the
                 'dump -Tv' command.
```

After learning that dnf was the successor to yum, I installed dnf using 'dnf_aixtoolbox.sh'. Any attempt to run dnf results in the below:

```
root@our_AIX_host:/opt/freeware/libexec > dnf
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /opt/freeware/libexec/python3.9_32 because of the following errors:
        0509-130 Symbol resolution failed for /usr/lib/libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) because:
        0509-136   Symbol _GLOBAL__AIXI_libintl_so (number 281) is not exported from
                   dependent module /usr/opt/rpm/lib/libintl.a(libintl.so.8).
        0509-136   Symbol _GLOBAL__AIXD_libintl_so (number 282) is not exported from
                   dependent module /usr/opt/rpm/lib/libintl.a(libintl.so.8).
        0509-026 System error: Error 0
        0509-192 Examine .loader section symbols with the
                 'dump -Tv' command.
```

I did run the below, and frankly I don't understand how to troubleshoot the output from here. I recognize that 'libintl.so.8' is a commonality between the above two outputs, but I don't understand what exactly it
's trying to tell me.

```
root@our_AIX_host:/opt/freeware/libexec > dump -Tv -X32_64 python3
```

I'm providing the final 10 lines of the output of the above command since there are ~1700 lines total. I can provide more if requested:

```
[1670]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) _Py_Sigset_Converter
[1671]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) _PyErr_CheckSignals
[1672]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) PyErr_SetInterrupt
[1673]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) PyOS_InitInterrupts
[1674]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) PyOS_InterruptOccurred
[1675]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) _PyOS_IsMainThread
[1676]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) PyTraceMalloc_Track
[1677]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) PyTraceMalloc_Untrack
[1678]  0x00000000    undef   ImpExp     DS EXTref libpython3.9.a(libpython3.9.so) _PyTraceMalloc_GetTraceback
[1679]  0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref libintl.a(libintl.so.8) _GLOBAL__AIXI_libintl_so
[1680]  0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref libintl.a(libintl.so.8) _GLOBAL__AIXD_libintl_so
[1681]  0x20000ff8    .data    ENTpt     DS SECdef        [noIMid] __start
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

From a now-deleted comment by [Lorinczy Zsigmond](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308515/lorinczy-zsigmond):

> You can try reordering LIBPATH: `/usr/local/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/lib`